# store image into Mysql database with url

Tags: php, mysql

i have inserting url of images into database table :first of all , the image is uploaded into a folder named uploads ( it is a sub folder of an other one named projet) in the server ( i'm using actually 000.webhost.com) , after that inserted in the table , the format of url actually is like that ( uploads/1494162719350.jpg).How Could i change the target_path( in the php code below) in order to obatin an url like(https://stationpfe.000webhostapp.com/projet/uploads/1494194541508.jpg ).
here is the structure of folders in the server .
[structure of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUEtb.png)

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require_once("db_connect.php");
$target_path = "uploads/";
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))  
{
//$image=basename( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],".jpg"); // used to store the filename in a variable

//storind the data in your database
//$QueryInsertFile="INSERT INTO TableName SET ImageColumnName='$target_path'"; 
$query= "INSERT INTO items SET pic='$target_path'";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "success";
} else 
{
echo $target_path;
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: please update your question, as it seems to be a problem with `move_uploaded_file`. What is the *real* problem ? image is neither move to file/server nor query saved ?

Comment: using the php code mentionned , the image is upladed in the uploads folder and in the database table (ex: uploads/1494196468977.jpg
).how to change the target_path in the php code   to get the absolute path ( from the server name to uploads/1494196468977.jpg for exemple )

Comment: well... I answered that, you said `the image doesn't appear in the uploads folder either in the database table` and now back to previous/same question ??? 1) is the image **actually** uploaded or not ? 2) what path do you have, and what would you like to have as the final path ?

Comment: Now , the url in the database tbale is uploads/1494196468977.jpg ( the image is stored in the uploads folder ) , the final path must be  https://stationpfe.000webhostapp.com/projet/uploads/image_name.jpg,it should be like that in order to get access to image with a client app

Comment: well, I answered that then ! use `$full_path = "https://stationpfe.000webhostapp.com/projet";` and when upload is done, add the `$target_path / img_name / whatever you have saved` to it -> concatenate the 2 vars and save it in DB -> you're done...